# Vuetify format cell based on item type

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm not sure if this can be done, but I would like to format some dynamically created columns based on a property. If the item does not have that property, I would like it to fall back to the default behavior.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to do (though the syntax is incorrect since you can't do item.type === foo in the template

```
<v-data-table :item="items" ... >
 <template #[`item.type === 'foo'`]="{ item } ">
   // Do a special format for any items that have a type of foo
 </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: Do you want to format a complete line or just a cell?

Comment: I would like to format the entire column if that row has the item.type

Comment: And is this in a particular column?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  The columns are being dynamically generated so I can't explicitly reference them by name

Comment: You're using a `headers` property on your table that references your columns right? Are you saying that this `headers` prop is being dynamically generated?

Comment: Yes, headers are being dynamically created

Comment: I do have the ability to add a prop/flag to the header if that makes this easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part here is that your headers are being dynamically generated. So you would have to use the dynamic slot name functionalities. This is not tested code but you could try something like this:

```
<v-data-table :item="items" ... >
 <template v-for="header in headers" v-slot:[`item.${header.value}`]="{ item } ">
   <template v-if="item.type === 'foo'">
     <span style="color: red;">{{ item[header.value] }}</span>
   </template>
   <template v-else>
     {{ item[header.value] }}
   </template>
 </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: Yep, this pretty much worked though I used header.type instead of item.type.  Thanks!!

Comment: I've got a followup question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65706435/vuetify-data-table-manually-display-expandable-rows

Answer (score 0):

hope the following example can help you:

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :item="items" ... >
    <template v-slot:item.type="{ item }">
        <div v-show="item.type == 'foo'">
        </div>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

and the header array should look like this:

```
data() {
    return {
        headers: [
        ...
        {
            text: '',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'type',
        },
        ...
        ]
    }
 }
```