# Vuetify data table - manually display expandable rows

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a bunch of dynamic columns in a v-data table which I need to loop through and interrogate in order to display the correct info. It looks a bit like this (taken from the answer here: [Vuetify format cell based on item type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65705012/vuetify-format-cell-based-on-item-type/65705237#65705237))

```
<v-data-table :item="items" ... >
 <template v-for="header in headers" v-slot:[`item.${header.value}`]="{ item } ">
   <template v-if="header.type === 'foo'">
     <span style="color: red;">{{ item[header.value] }}</span>
   </template>
   <template v-else-if="header.value === 'data-table-expand'">
     ???
   </template>
   <template v-else>
     {{ item[header.value] }}
   </template>
 </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Since I need the v-if statement, all other types default to the v-else.  However, the v-else is not suitable for when a type is an expandable row.  It will display a blank value for that column.  So I created a v-else-if template to be able to capture the expandable row column and correctly render it to the screen.

The problem is that I don't know what to put in the template to indicate it's a column with expandable rows (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#expandable-rows).  In other words it does not render the carat icon that shrinks/expands the subtable, nor does it render the clickable actions.  How would I modify the v-else-if template to correctly render its contents?

Comment: Are you looking for [chevron-down](https://materialdesignicons.com/icon/chevron-down)?

Comment: No, I'm looking for the code that renders the icon and all it's functionality when clicked on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a workaround using computed properties.

Instead of using

```
v-for="header in headers"
```

I changed it to a computed headers which is filtered.

```
<template v-for="header in headersIWant" v-slot:[`item.${header.value}`]="{ item } ">
  <span style="color: red;">{{ item[header.value] }}</span>
</template>
...
computed: {
 headersIWant() {
  return this.headers.filter(x => x.type === 'foo');
 }
}
```